# Grouping based on columns present in list in a loop

Tags: python

I have a list of columns : `cols = [“policy_yr”,”policy_month”,policy_no”,”premium”]`

I need to group by each elements of the list one by one and for each group I need to find count, sum,min,max of rest of the elements and store it in a single data frame

e.g.

```
df.groupby(“policy_yr”)[[”policy_month”,policy_no”,”premium”]].min()

df.groupby(“policy_yr”)[[”policy_month”,policy_no”,”premium”]].max()

df.groupby(“policy_yr”)[[”policy_month”,policy_no”,”premium”]].sum()

df.groupby(“policy_yr”)[[”policy_month”,policy_no”,”premium”]].count()
```

All the above values should be stored in a single data frame and also the next group by output on `policy_month` should be added in same data frame and so on for rest of elements in the list

Comment: Please give example data.

Comment: df = policy_yr  policy_month  policy_no. Premium.

Comment: My data frame consist of columns [ policy_year, policy_month,policy_no,premium]with values and I need to group by each column and find aggregates for rest of columns and store it in a single dataframe

Comment: Can't you use a library?(pandas)